# How do I refer to a swear word without saying it?

Tags: slang

What is the correct way to indicate a specific swear word without actually writing it? Such as H--- instead of "hell."

Comment: Morse code, Base64 encoding, DES encryption.

Comment: One technique is to say the first letter of the word, and then "-word"; for example, F-word, S-word, and N-word.  However, many people are so desensitized to "damn" and "Hell" that they would be puzzled by D-word and H-word.

Comment: My aunt always said, “Aitch Eeh double hockey sticks”

Comment: Act like an adult and just write out the word unless you will suffer the consequences of automated editing.  This is so silly.

Answer (score 2):

Using asterisks like H*** is pretty common, or just make the whole word asterisks like ****